# issue with Gmail email/smtp to send mails from website but work fine on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gmail

I have problem with Gmail Smtp Client. The email works on localhost but when i publish the site online its stops working.

This is the code ASP.net MVC C#

```
public void SendEMail(EmailFormModel user)
{

    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage Msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    Msg.Subject = "Contact US";
    Msg.From = new MailAddress("omar.fwziii@gmail.com", "admin");
    Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("omar.fwzi@yahoo.com"));
    Msg.Body = user.Message;
    Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false; 
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("omar.fwziii@gmail.com", "pASSW0RD");
    smtp.Send(Msg);
}
```

NOTE IM USING SOMEE fREE HOSTING AND I TRIED TO SWITCH THE PORT TO 25 , 26 , AND 465

Comment: When you login to gmail from a different location (usually geographical) google temporarily locks your account until you can confirm that it was you who tried to login from the new location. Try logging in manually through a browser to see if you are prompted with a dialog. Or check the inbox of that account. Also, this could be a problem as well - https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: It is most likely not working because you did not authorize the unrecognized login from your production server. I would try to login to gmail and look for an email they should have sent you. Try to follow the instructions to remove the lock. As far as other smtp clients go, you could create another gmail, yahoo, etc. Also be mindful that if you plan to send hundreds of emails through gmail, they will block you.

Comment: i remember that google gave me alert about different location but i couldn't check that it was me also i turned on the less security app it didn't work is there any smtp client i can use ?

Comment: solve it using Zoho mail Thanks ... regards